# My Enderdragon texture appears but it's white?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Just to preface this:: I edit my own textures for Minecraft. I've done so since Beta 1.3.

Now-- I edited the original texture for my Enderdragon when it launched in the update. I believe it worked at the time, but has since stopped (sort of). And now it appears as a whitened version of the texture in-game.

The Enderdragon Head/mask still displays my texture normally, but not the dragon itself. So the game clearly recognizes it. OH! And my eyes still appear on the model. Very odd. Would really appreciate an explanation so that I can fix it.

[image: The texture technically shows up but it's white? It's supposed to be dark purple]

Comment: What does the texture look like? You may have it layed out wrong, causing this.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 Agreed. The most likely answer is the texture is invalid. Also make sure that the file format is PNG. Obvious but easy to overlook.

Answer (score -1):

if blocks and mods are white that means there is ether a Error in the texture Or rendering (like a computer who doesnt have enough Memory to render)

also form what i khow Just like spiders and enderman the eyes use a Other texture then the main mob 
this to make the eyes glow